# Send and receive on RabbitMQ fanout exchange via Spring

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm working with RabbitMQ and I'm confused using fanout exchange and `convertSendAndReceive` (or `sendAndReceive`) method of `RabbitTemplate` class.

For example, I have 2 consumers for durable queues QUEUE-01 and QUEUE-02 that are binded to durable fanout exchange FANOUT-01. And 1 publisher to FANOUT-01. I understand what happens when message is being published with `convertAndSend` (or `send`) method, message is going to be copied to each queue and will be processed by each consumer. But I'm not sure what will happen if I will call `sendAndReceive` method? Which consumer will I get a reply from? Is there any specific behaviour? I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendAndReceive()` is not appropriate for `fanout` messaging; it is indeterminate as to which reply will win (the first one, generally). If you want to handle multiple replies and aggregate them you will need to use discrete `send` and `receive` calls (or listener container for the replies) and do the aggregation yourself.

Consider using [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) for such situations. It has built-in components for aggregating messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is exactly what I thought would happen, but did not find any proves. Could you plese provide some more information on _use discrete `send` and `receive` calls_? Maybe there are some examples?

Comment: `receive()` doesn't block (although there is an option to do so in the upcoming 1.5 release). So it's probably easiest to use an async consumer for the replies. I am not aware of any specific example for your use case, but it should be pretty easy to set up; see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/).

Answer (score 2):

The method `sendAndReceive` in the `RabbitTemplate` is used for when you would like to use RPC style messaging.  There is an excellent tutorial [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).